# Can't see new answer

Tags: support, deleted-answer

I had posted this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/379428/how-to-burn-hd-videos-with-menu-system-onto-dvd-media/) a few months ago. It had only received one answer to date. When I visited the site a couple of days ago, I saw the notification in my inbox of a new answer. But when I clicked onto the page, it still showed only the old answer. I can see the beginning excerpt of the new answer in the notification area but it's invisible on the question's page. Help.

Thanks.

Comment: Not a great loss. The full answer was: "*[Product] can easily burn all sorts of videos into DVD discs. With this DVD burner software, [Product], you can convert almost all video formats from video downloads to camcorder videos, including MKV, MP4, AVI, M2TS, TS, MOV, WMV, WMA, 3GP, FLV, M4V, VOB, etc. It can burn video to any DVD with great output effect, such as DVD9, DVD5, DVD+R/RW, DVD-R/RW, DVD+R DL and DVD-R DL.*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answer was spam flagged and consequently deleted.